# Timer job for the update of ViewsLifeTime

Tags: 2013, view, timer-jobs, analytics

Which timer job controls the update of the ViewsLifeTime?

Answer (score 2):

The following Two timer jobs are responsible for push analytic data like `the life time view count of a page (ViewsLifeTime)` into the Analytics database.

- Analytics Timer Job for Search Service Application.
- Usage Analytics Timer Job for Search Application.

Comment: Hi I have tried this and it hasn't worked.  I ran both job checked and the number of views didn't increase.  For good measure I also ran a full crawl yet no change....